# Kafka Streams: Store state during rebalance

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

While in the middle of traversing through the iterator in the periodic execution of punctuate method, if a rebalance occurs would the below loop stop OR throw an exception?  Or would it resume automatically, if so would it resume with the same partition shard?

```
    KeyValue<String, House> curr;
    KeyValueIterator<String, House> houseIterator = houseStore.all();
    while (houseIterator.hasNext()) {
        j++;
        curr = houseIterator.next();
        houseStore.delete(curr.key);
    }
    houseIterator.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The executing thread will not call `KafkaConsumer#poll()` until `punctuate()` is finished. Thus, the thread (ie, `punctuate`) will continue the run.

If `punctuate()` finishes before `max.poll.interval.ms` passed, it will rebalance correctly. If `punctuate` finished after `max.poll.interval.ms` the consumer would drop out of the consumer group, and it partitions might get reassigned. However, depending on your code within `punctuate`, it would not be noticed and `punctuate` might still finish. Later, when `poll` is called, the instance would rejoin the group via another rebalance.

Note though, that it is recommended to configure `max.poll.interval.ms` such that the instances does not drop out of the consumer group in the first place. Ie, the value should be set to a larger value than the expected runtime of `punctuate`.